# How do I stop a docker container so it will rerun with the same command?

Tags: docker

I start my docker container with a name.  like this:

```
docker run --name regsvc my-registrationservice
```

If I call docker stop regsvc, the next time I run the above command it fails.  I have to run these commands first.

```
docker kill regsvc
docker system prune
```

That seems excessive.  Is there a better way to stop the container and restart it?

Thnx
Matt

Comment: Can't you just do `docker start regsvc` again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to run a new container every time you issue `docker run` and it would be better for you to use `--rm` flag:

```
docker run --rm --name regsvc my-registrationservice
```

This will remove the container when your container exits. This is better if you don't want to save data of container.

As suggested by @trong-lam-phan you could restart your existing container using

```
docker restart regsvc
```

Answer (score 3):

When you stop a container, you can still see it with:

```
docker ps -a
```

Now the container is not alive but it is still there. So, you only need to restart it if you want it to work again:

```
docker restart regsvc
```

The command **docker run** will create a container from your image. So if you want to use **docker run** again, you need firstly remove your container (after stop it):

```
docker rm regsvc
docker run --name regsvc my-registrationservice
```