# How do I stop my Docker Windows container from the command line?

Tags: windows, docker, command-line

I have a Docker Windows container that I want to stop from the command line. Seems like an easy thing to do, but the commands

```
docker stop my-docker-machine
```

and

```
docker kill my-docker-machine
```

produce the error

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: my-docker-machine
```

---

I've searched the following without success:

- [Windows Containers on Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server)
- [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/)
- [How do I stop a docker container so it will rerun with the same command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681121/how-do-i-stop-a-docker-container-so-it-will-rerun-with-the-same-command)

---

### How do I stop my Docker Windows container from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try using the `stop` command with the container id instead of the name:

```
Docker stop ab44b99065ce
```

Works much better!

---

Edit: You might want a list of container id's first. As pointed out by [Varun Babu Pozhath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6685184/varun-babu-pozhath), you can use

`docker ps` to list all running containers or

`docker ps -all` to list all containers.

Comment: `docker ps` will list all running containers. `docker ps -all` will list all containers